# Jquery validator change `this` ES6 code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, jquery-validate, es6-class

I have es6 class with constructor and validation method.

```
class Popups {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.app = selector;
  }

  validate() {
    $.validator.addMethod('atLeastOneLowercaseLetter', (value, element) => {
        return this.optional(element) || /[a-z]+/.test(value);
        // how to replace `this` ??
      },
      'Must have at least one lowercase letter'
    );
  }
}
```

My `this` refers to my Class, but I need get `$.validator` with my validate form. How i can replace this?

If i write `$.validator.optional(element) || /[a-z]+/.test(value)` I get error `$.validator.optional is not a function`

Comment: I'm assuming you know how the arrow functions work, so, you can use the object `$.validator` directly inside that handler.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use normal `function`. I need '=>'

Comment: @Ele `$.validator` don't have my form, i don't know how i can send myform into `$.validator`

Comment: @РоманТатаринов You can't use `=>`. Why do you think you "need" it, why don't you just use a working `function`?

Answer (score 1):

In that case don't use an [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function as it *does not have it's own `this`*. Use a normal function expression as the callback instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use normal `function`

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve a downvote because is an alternative.

Comment: @РоманТатаринов what's the reason for not using a function expression?

Comment: @Kristianmitk project have es-linting, when is prohibited to use normal `function`